# ActionBar tabs and onPrepareOptionsMenu behaviour

Tags: android, tabs, android-fragments, android-actionbar, optionmenu

My app uses tab navigation with Actionbar Sherlock to switch between two fragments each with their own listview. Also, each fragment has it's own options menu associated with it, so within my two fragment classes I've made use of:

```
@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);
    ...
}
```

For one of the fragments, its important to have some of the options in its options menu greyed out depending on which items the user has selected in its list. I've done this by calling:

```
@Override
public void onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu){
        ...
}
```

Within this method, I identify which items in the list have been checked. I've noticed that when I switch between tabs, onPrepareOptionsMenu get called right away. Then the very next time I press the menu key, onPrepareOptionsMenu is not called, and the available options in the menu are not updated. When I hit the menu button a second time, everything works fine and the available options get updated. Is there I way I can enforce onPrepareOptionsMenu gets called when the menu key is pressed following a tab switch?

I've seen notes about using invalidateOptionsMenu() to trigger onPrepareOptionsMenu, but it seems messy to override the menu key event every time while this issue only comes up the first time the user presses the menu key. Is there a better way?

Comment: I just noticed that my title should say behavior not behavoir. Spending too much time thinking about the problem rather than my spelling. Sorry.

Comment: Try using `onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)` instead.